# excel vba sum in loop and capturing the cell values need to sum

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel with two worksheets that have data. The first worksheet is called monthly and has a list of people and an expense amount and date of expense.  This is entered as the expense is turned in.  On the second work sheet I am attempting to copy the data from the first worksheet then sort by the person.  Insert two blank rows between each person then put a subtotal for each person.  I have figured out how to do the first 3 steps.  (might not be the best way but it works)  I could use some help on how to get the sum of each person on the second worksheet in the first blank line that I created.  I might also have a looping error when it is trying to determine where to put in the blank rows.

Here is a screen shot of the Monthly worksheet:

[image: Here is a screen shot of the Monthly worksheet]

Here is a screen shot of the YTD worksheet:

[image: Here is a screen shot of the YTD worksheet]

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'create variable for max row count of E
    Dim rowcount As Double
    Dim rowcount2 As Double
    'Max row count of E to use in copy
    rowcount = Sheets("Monthly").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Select Data Copy data
    Sheets("Monthly").Range("A5:E" & rowcount).Copy Destination:=Sheets("YTD `Total").Range("A5")`
    rowcount2 = Sheets("YTD Total").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Sort Rows by Employee in YTD
    Dim onerange As Range
    Dim acell As Range
    Set onerange = Sheets("YTD Total").Range("A5:E" & rowcount2)
    Set acell = Sheets("YTD Total").Range("A5")
    onerange.Sort Key1:=acell, Order1:=xlAscending
    'insert blank rows between Employee
    Dim emp1 As String
    Dim emp2 As String
    Dim count1 As Double
    Dim count2 As Double
    Dim rowcount3 As Double
    Dim counter As Double
    Dim currentcell As String
    Dim sum1 As Double
    Dim sum2 As Double

    rowcount3 = Sheets("YTD Total").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    count1 = "5"
    count2 = "6"
    For Each Cell In Sheets("YTD Total").Range("A5:A12")
    '" & rowcount3)
        emp1 = Sheets("YTD Total").Range("A" & count1)
        emp2 = Sheets("YTD Total").Range("A" & count2)

        If emp1 = emp2 Then
        count1 = count1 + 1
        count2 = count2 + 1

    '    ElseIf emp1 <> emp2 And emp1 = Null Then
    '    count1 = count1 + 1
    '    count2 = count2 + 1
    '    ElseIf emp1 = Null And emp2 = Null Then
    '    count1 = count1 + 1
    '    count2 = count2 + 1
        Else
        Range("A" & count2).EntireRow.Insert
        Range("A" & count2).EntireRow.Insert
        currentcell = Cell.Address
       Range("C" & (count2)) = sum1

        count1 = count1 + 3
        count2 = count2 + 3
        End If
    Next Cell


    End Sub

    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim Answer As String
    Dim MyNote As String

        'Place your text here
        MyNote = "Are you sure you want to Delete content?  Please be aware if no data in A5 you will delete your headers"

        'Display MessageBox
        Answer = MsgBox(MyNote, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "???")

        If Answer = vbNo Then
            'Code for No button Press
            MsgBox "You pressed NO!"
        Else
    Lastrow = Sheets("YTD Total").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A5", "E" & Lastrow).ClearContents
        End If
    End Sub
```

Here is some data to copy into excel:

```
AAA 12345-001   1.40    Expense
AAA 12345-002   0.25    Expense
BBB 67819-001   1.25    Expense
AAA 67819-002   5.00    Expense
AAA 11111-001   5.85    Expense
BBB 11111-001   0.05    Expense
CCC 22222-002   0.95    Expense
CCC 22222-003   5.00    Expense
DDD 12345-001   1.30    Expense
BBB 11111-001   0.25    Expense
DDD 12345-001   5.40    Expense
AAA 22222-003   7.70    Expense
BBB 22222-001   5.75    Expense
```

Comment: Why not use a pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

In summary, I added the following variables:

```
Dim rcount1 As Long
Dim rcount2 As Long
Dim rng as Range
```

Then I just changed your `for` loop to this:

```
For Each Cell In Sheets("YTD Total").Range("A5:A12")
emp1 = Sheets("Monthly").Range("A" & count1)
emp2 = Sheets("Monthly").Range("A" & count2)

If emp1 = emp2 Then
count1 = count1 + 1
count2 = count2 + 1
rcount1 = rcount1 + 1
rcount2 = rcount2 + 1

Else
Range("A" & count2).EntireRow.Insert
Range("A" & count2).EntireRow.Insert
currentcell = Cell.Address

Set rng = Range("C" & (count2 - 1) & ":C" & Range("C" & (count2) - 1).End(xlUp).Row)
Range("C" & (count2)).Formula = "=SUM(" & rng.Address(flase, flase) & ")"

count1 = count1 + 3
count2 = count2 + 3
count1 = count1 + 1
count2 = count2 + 1
End If
Next Cell
```

Hope this at least gets your pointed in the right direction!